# understanding JBOSS and its services

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, middleware

I am a junior developer, and have done considerable web application development using apache tomcat and quite comfortable with it.

I want to start using the JBOSS and quite new to it, though I can deploy a web application through eclipse. But the thing is that I am finding JBOSS very intidamiting and overwhelming.

I want to understand the ins and outs of JBOSS and all the services it provide.

What should be my starting point and what should be my strategy?
Also, please let me know if there are any prerequisites that I need to understand before understanding JBOSS.

Your help will be very appreciated.

regards
adofo

Comment: No really a good question. Which version of JBoss do you want to learn? JBoss 7 is a complete rewrite and design compared to its previous releases.

Comment: I am currently working in JBOSS 6 Final

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are still looking into this, but I'd recommend [JBoss in Action](http://www.manning.com/jamae/) if you are still looking to learn about JBoss 6. I believe it covers up to JBoss 5, but I believe that most of the concepts are transferable. I own it and have found it to be a good resource.

As far as prerequisites, if you have been using Tomcat, then you probably have what you need to begin using JBoss. You don't need to use the services. They are there if you want them, but you can always add your own frameworks and do things the way you want to. For example, where I'm currently working I added CXF for web services instead of using the JBoss stack for web services (even though it actually uses CXF at some level). I would recommend using JBoss' logging however versus adding your own.

The hardest part of using JBoss is dealing with ClassCastExceptions. There are multiple class loaders and frameworks can be loaded from higher level directories within JBoss. A class may be loaded from one class loader and then an attempt to use a dependent class may come from a different class loader. Even though the class name is the same, because it came from a different class loader, the JVM sees it as a different class. These can be maddening to attempt to resolve. The aforementioned book gives *some* tips on dealing with this and explains it a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following topics with links

1. [This](http://www.roseindia.net/jboss/buildingwebapplicationwithant.shtml) (and [this](http://www.centerkey.com/jboss/)) link, describes a simple tutorials for deploying a web application in JBoss. Though this describes an  EAR deployment, you can simply deploy war file as well.
   2.Then check [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest-dev/en/Beginners_Guide/html_single/index.html) for all the services provided by JBoss server.
2. I found [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/) link also very useful.

   I am not sure if this helps you or you are looking for any specific pointers.

Comment: How do you know that the OP is interested in JBoss 7? That's the problem we have with this question.

Comment: You are right as OP does not mention the JBoss version. But I assumed since is at a beginner's level (from working on JBoss perspective),OP would be working on whats latest unless specified otherwise. Offcourse, as you mentioned, my assumption may be invalid.